# Table is shown only when querying using databasename.tablename

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

Using mysql workbench. the database is called accountdb. I just imported a table called "keys" (should've used a better name).
The table is there when I query this:

> show tables;

When querying using

> SELECT * FROM accountdb.keys;

The table is successfully returned:
11:52:29    SELECT * FROM accountdb.keys ...

When querying using

> SELECT * FROM keys;

I see an error.
11:56:01    SELECT * FROM keys  Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax ...

Oddly enough, when I query any other tables, e.g.

> select* from address;

I still get the correct results. So this problem is unique to the table that I imported.

Any ideas? Thanks a lot guys!

Comment: `keys` is a reserved word. You need to escape it if you want to use it as a table name.

Comment: The clue is that it says you have a syntax error, not that the table doesn't exist.